# Replace Digits Authentication with Firebase Phone/Auth in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-authentication, twitter-digits

I want to replace the Digits OTP verification in my iOS app, with Firebase Phone/Auth(for obvious reasons). I do not need the Google, Email and Facebook Login features.

The documentation in Firebase is leading to setup a `ViewController` that forces the user to chooses the mode of login.
Is there a way to directly send the user to the Phone Number login page?

Also, can I accomplish this without messing around with Push Services?

Comment: The Firebase Authentication documentation for Phone number verification does not show any such picker. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth

Comment: If you're using FirebaseUI, can you check what you're setting for authUi.providers? It should only have Phone, and not Google or others. If you can paste in the code you're using to configure, we can check.